# Get latest NodeJS in Debian environment

Tags: node.js, docker, debian

I am trying to create a docker image from a Debian environment and I am unable to obtain NodeJS ver. 6.*.

I am running:  `RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential`

in my dockerfile but the `nodejs` version is still 4.8.2. I've tried doing `apt-get update` but the version stays at 4.8.2 for `nodejs`.

Comment: How about just starting with the official NodeJS image?  https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Comment: Also, why keep us guessing at what is going on? Just post the `Dockerfile` and commands used so someone can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the Node directly (because e.g. you need to use this specific Debian base image for some reason) then you may try to get the official Node package instead of the one that you're using with something like:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo chown -Rv root.root node-v6.7.0-linux-x64
sudo cp -Rvi node-v6.7.0-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Just change the version to the one that you want. See my tutorial for more options and more ways to do it:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

Another options is to use `nvm` which is very solid Node version manager:

- https://github.com/creationix/nvm#readme

If you can use some other Docker base image then consider one that already has the correct version of Node included, like https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ as advised by tier1 in the comments.